# To create a python "web script" to list all directories and files in the folder

Tags: python, macos

Here is my script.

```
 import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
# print path to all subdirectories first.
for subdirname in dirnames:
    print os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)

# print path to all filenames.
for filename in filenames:
    print os.path.join(dirname, filename)

# Advanced usage:
# editing the 'dirnames' list will stop os.walk() from recursing into there.
if '.git' in dirnames:
    # don't go into any .git directories.
    dirnames.remove('.git')
```

I am using the command line : python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000  on mac terminal. Now i want to run the above script from browser. It simply doesnot work, and just outputs the content of the file. How to make it run ( the way PHP files run and list directories on apache web server ) .

Comment: Use Python webframework like bottle or flask

Answer (score 0):

You should check the doc's:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer

In order for your script/function to run you'd have to use your own HTTPServer, e.g. by inheriting from the `SimpleHTTPServer` and overloading the `list_directories()` to produce your listing.
In that case however, you'd have to return a string containing the actual HTML representation of your filelist.